# php plus number keep zero as first character

Tags: php, variables, numbers

I have this code:

```
$i = '0001';
$j = $i + 1;
```

I want to get 0002 but it give me only 2
How can I plus $i and keep that 000?

Thank you

Comment: Use [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format a number in a particular manner. Something like `sprintf('%04d', $j)` or similar.

Comment: Numeric types do not have leading zeroes, but strings can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can give you an idea:

```
$i = '0001';
$i = intval($i);
$i++;
$a = '000';
$result = $a.$i;
echo $result;
```

The `.` between `$a` and `$i` is concatenating the variables into a string, keeping every character in them.
The code above will output `0002`
Check it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc2bd5861a6c0d937568b067e98e06977741019c

If you want to keep all leading zeroes, you could count them separately and increment it like this. Of course, this is something whipped out quickly and I'm 100% certain there are much better ways of doing this out there.

Comment: The problem here is that once the value reaches `10` the output becomes a five digit string: `00010`. Both `str_pad()` and `sprintf()` avoid that.

Comment: That's very true; that case did skip my mind! Indeed the other two are fit for this better than what I suggested, the very reason why I wrote the last part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_pad to keep the leading zeroes.

Code here,

```
<?php
$i = '0001';
$val = $i + 1;
echo str_pad($val,4,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); // 0001
?>
```

[Click to learn more about str_pad](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_pad.asp)

Answer (score 0):

PHP took a useful feature from Perl: the ability to increment strings, using `++`. Unfortunately, it didn't do it very well. If you increment `"A0001"`, you get `"A0002"`; but if you increment `"0001"`, you get `2` (as opposed to original Perl, which would give you `"0002"`). But, you can cheat:

```
$i="0001";
$j=":$a";
$j++;
$j=substr($j, 1);
```

This is more to both illustrate a cool thing not many people might be aware of, and how it was misimplemented, than to provide a real solution; I would definitely prefer to see a `str_pad` or `sprintf` solution in my code.